# Setting Custom Form on Expense Reports

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am new to SuiteScript and am trying to figure out how to run scripts on only certain record types. For example, I want to set a custom form on only certain types of expense reports. How does the script know to only run on Expense Reports and how can I tell it to only run on expense reports where FieldA = "SomeValue"?

Here is the start of a script that I believe may be correct, but I am not 100% sure. Any help is appreciated.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/

function expenseBeforeLoad() {

}

define(['N/record','N/search','N/ui/dialog', 'N/log'], function (record, search, dialog, log) {
    
    function pageInit(context) {
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
        
        currentRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'customform',
            value: 'Travel Expense Form'
        });        
    }
    
    return {
        pageInit: pageInit
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the biggest problem with your script is that you have identified it as a User Event script in the JSDOC section (`/**...*/`), but the script returns an entry point function for the `pageInit` event, which belongs on a Client script.

Secondly, to answer your question about how to run a script on a specific record type, this varies by script type, but is similar for both User Event scripts and record level Client scripts.  You need three things for a script to run:

1. A script file.  This is a text file stored in the NetSuite file cabinet with a .js extension.  For SuiteScript 2.x it needs to have a valid JSDOC section specifying the version and script type, and generally needs to implement at least one of the the entry point functions designated by NetSuite for that script type.
2. A script record.  This is created by going to Customization > Scripting > Scripts > New and filling the details, including selecting the script file.
3. A script deployment.  This can be created from the script record by clicking the Deploy button.  This is where you select what record type the script is to run on, along with other filtering options like the event or context.